# Combine raster values for overlapping cells of multiple rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2

How do I combine the values of cells for 3 rasters for cells where they overlap. I want the output raster to cover only the area of the overlap for the 3 rasters and the output cell values to be a sum of the values of the 3 original rasters.

I am using arcmap 10.2. If this is possible through raster calculator it will be preferable. Or any of the spatial analyst tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm) can do this -- indeed, the example illustration on the help page shows exactly what you want to do. The resulting raster will only cover the overlap area, which I often find problematic for my analyses but sounds like what you need.

[image]

Other options would work but are more complex than you need. The [Plus](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Plus/009z00000096000000/) tool only adds two rasters at a time and would involve running the tool twice. The [Weighted Sum](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Weighted_Sum/009z000000rr000000/) tool could work if you assign a weight of 1 to all the rasters. I'd just stick with Raster Calculator.

Comment: Thank you all. What about nodata, I hope nodata values are ignored in the calculation?

Comment: Yes, NoData is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The tool to do this is called [cell statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007q000000.htm)

Select the option SUM

In the environments setting ([Output Extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000009000000)) set the output extent to intersect

Comment: Yes, I'd forgotten about Cell Statistics :)